Wix5 Rookie question ; how to add a custom action that create a file and its content based on install infos?
In Wix5,
I tried to add a custom action that run at the end of the install and that create a file whose content is the install directory path
I tried the following :
<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ExampleComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

<ComponentGroupRef Id="Package1"/>

  </ComponentGroup>
 <Binary Id="vbsexecutionTest" SourceFile="createFile.vbs"/>
 <Property Id="CustomActionData" Value="CIRO"/>
 <CustomAction Id="LaunchMyApp" BinaryRef="vbsexecutionTest"
                  VBScriptCall=""                   
            Execute="deferred" Return="check"  />
 <!-- Define a custom action that launches the embedded binary -->
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchMyApp" After="InstallFiles"/>
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Fragment>

But I don't find the way to pass a parameter ...
Maybe vb script is not the right way ?

Note: VBScript is being deprecated in Windows. VB Script is not the right way going forward.

You could avoid the custom action by writing an INI file or XML file: <IniFile Id="InstallConfig" Directory="PUT-DIRECTORY-ID-HERE" Name="installconfig.ini" Section="main" Key="InstallFolder" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]"/>. For XML have a look at the util:XmlFile element.

@zett42 Thank you!
my file has to be in json format, with several keys in it.
I think I'll try to use
https://github.com/hegsie/WixJsonFileExtension
then

@zett42 : Please provide your answer: in this way I will accept it has the right answer to the post

Finally found the right way to do it:
1st a big thanks to this site:
How to pass Custom Actions to a WIX Installer using command line arguments
So the right method is to create a DLL
and in particular a Custom Action One
A custom action project creates a file with reference to the DTF
using WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller;
cf WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller namespace 
With such a configuration the properties inside the wsx files are visibile in the DLL via the session statement
 session["INSTALLFOLDER"] for example read the value of the property with Id INSTALLFOLDER
Then add the CustomActionCode.CA.dll to your wsx as binary and ... create a custom action as per below
<CustomAction 
       Id="LaunchMyApp" 
       BinaryRef="* ID of the binary *"
       DllEntry="* static public function defined in the DLL 
                  and tagged in the DLL as  [CustomAction] *"           
       Return="check"  
/>


Thanks to Christopher  and it's answer in Custom Action in C# used via WiX fails with error 1154\
